# Swift update vertical constraint to be at top superview

Tags: swift

As you can see from the image below, I have a purple UIView, and directly under the UIView I have another UIView.

[image]

This is inside of a `UITableView`, and programmatically, I am removing the purple box from the superview on specific indexPaths. The problem I have facing is that the UIView under the purple view disappears after each indexPath once I show the purple view.... I assume I have to bring back that UIView.

I have set up an outlet for that constraint inside of my cell

```
@IBOutlet var topUIViewContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and I call it from my `UITableViews cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CellItems {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let responseItems = resultsModelArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(item: responseItems)
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        if (indexPath.row != 1) {
            cell.adViewLayout.removeFromSuperview()
            //cell.topUIViewContraint.
            userItemsTableView.rowHeight = 490.0
        } else {
            userItemsTableView.rowHeight = 600.0
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return CellItems()
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to set it up on this line..

```
// cell.topUIViewContraint.
```

but how do I set this to be the superview top with 8 padding?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Would be nice if you post the whole UITableViewCell subclass.
Besides that, remember that those cells are being reused, so after you remove `adViewLayout` from the cell and scroll a little bit UITableView might reuse that cell and it won't have the `adViewLayout` anymore. It's also strange that you are setting the table view's row height inside that function, that will bring problems.

Comment: i dont see how much the entire subclass is needed. it pretty much sets up my view, nothing much to it.... what is the best option to show/hide that UIview at specific rows?  if I add that purple view in, I need the height of that cell to be higher, otherwise it will end up being cut off.

Comment: There are many ways of doing it. You could let Autolayout handle everything, for that you need to check UITableViewCells with automatic dimensions.
You could also have 2 different cells and use the one you need.

Comment: @letsCode what is your goal at the end? Is your goal to remove ad add back the purple view on some index path? if yes maybe you could just set the background color of it to clear color this way you keep all constraints

Comment: no @Abv. the purple view IS my adview. im just styling it purple to see it on device. i want the purple view at index 1 and 10. im only testing 1 for right now. i want to show at 1 and 10, and hide at all of the others.

Comment: @GustavoConde let me try adding another cell and go from there.... thanks!

Comment: You need to have 2 cells, one with the adView one without. For each cell using autolayout, you need to constraint vertically all the views. For example, adView.top to contentView.top, adView.height, label.top to adView.bottom, label.bottom to contentView.bottom. Label height is not necessary as it would use the intrinsic content size but you can add it if you want. Then in rowHeight you need to set UITableView.automaticDimension. Same for the cell without adView. Then on cellForRowAt check the indexPath and dequeue one type of cell or the other.